# Can`t connect my MySQL database in Vapor project

Tags: swift, vapor, fluent-orm

I'm new at Vapor and I wanted to try to connect my MySQL database. I found on official documentation how to do it but when I try to send a query it throws an error:

`No services are available for 'DatabaseConnectionPoolCache'. (Container.swift:112)`

I just copy-paste the code from documentation and it doesn`t work. Could someone help me to found out why?

I have **MySQL@5.7** on **Mojave**. Actually simple requests work well, for example :

```
router.get("hey") { req in
    return "Stas, hey"
}
```

Code in configure.swift :

```
import FluentSQLite
import MySQL
import Vapor

/// Called before your application initializes.
public func configure(_ config: inout Config, _ env: inout Environment, _ services: inout Services) throws {
    /// Register providers first
    try services.register(FluentSQLiteProvider())
    try services.register(MySQLProvider())

    /// Register routes to the router
    let router = EngineRouter.default()
    try routes(router)
    services.register(router, as: Router.self)

    /// Register middleware
    var middlewares = MiddlewareConfig() // Create _empty_ middleware config
    /// middlewares.use(FileMiddleware.self) // Serves files from `Public/` directory
    middlewares.use(ErrorMiddleware.self) // Catches errors and converts to HTTP response
    services.register(middlewares)

    // Configure a SQLite database
    let sqlite = try SQLiteDatabase(storage: .memory)

    /// Register the configured SQLite database to the database config.
    var databases = DatabasesConfig()
    databases.add(database: sqlite, as: .sqlite)
    services.register(databases)

    /// Configure migrations
    var migrations = MigrationConfig()
    migrations.add(model: Todo.self, database: .sqlite)
    services.register(migrations)

    //Configure a MySQL database
    let mysql = try MySQLDatabase(config: MySQLDatabaseConfig(
        hostname: "127.0.0.1",
        port: 3306,
        username: "root",
        password: "7374",
        database: "WORK_TIME"))

    ///Register to the congig
    var mysqlDatabases = DatabasesConfig()
    mysqlDatabases.add(database: mysql, as: .mysql)
    services.register(mysqlDatabases) 
}
```

My query in main.swift :

```
public struct MySQLVersion: Codable {
    let version: String
}

router.get("sql") { req in
    return req.withPooledConnection(to: .mysql) {conn in
        return conn.raw("SELECT @@version as version")
            .all(decoding: MySQLVersion.self)
        }.map { rows in
            return rows[0].version
    }
}
```

It should return the version of my MySQL but it throws a strange error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that there is some leftover SQLite stuff from the original project template.

Start by removing the `fluent-sqlite` dependency from your `Package.swift` file and the `FluentSQLite` target from any target dependencies. Then run `swift package update` (and `vapor xcode` if you use Xcode) in your terminal.

Now that you have removed the `FluentSQLite` dependency from your project, you should be able to follow to compiler errors to fix your issue. Here are the ones I found:

---

```
import FluentSQLite
import MySQL
```

Should be:

```
import FluentMySQL
```

---

```
try services.register(FluentSQLiteProvider())
try services.register(MySQLProvider())
```

Should be

```
try services.register(FluentMySQLProvider())
```

---

Delete this, since you are using MySQL instead of SQLite:

```
// Configure a SQLite database
let sqlite = try SQLiteDatabase(storage: .memory)

/// Register the configured SQLite database to the database config.
var databases = DatabasesConfig()
databases.add(database: sqlite, as: .sqlite)
services.register(databases)
```

---

```
migrations.add(model: Todo.self, database: .sqlite)
```

Should be

```
migrations.add(model: Todo.self, database: .mysql)
```

---

I think that covers everything. Your `/sql` route should work now.

Comment: Unfortunately, the samу error. Probably, is there an error in migrations ? (I think like that because of the `.sqlite` there) `var migrations = MigrationConfig()` `migrations.add(model: Todo.self, database: .sqlite)` `services.register(migrations)`

Comment: @StanislavMarynych Yes, I missed that. The `Todo` migration should use `.mysql`. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Ohh, I am so sorry i found my mistake, now it works)

Comment: It was such a silly error, I had to write my routes in `routes.swift`, not in `main.swift`. Thank you for help!

Comment: @StanislavMarynych That's great! You can post your own answer to your question and accept it once you are allowed to (you have to wait 24h or so).

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem you should get rid of all leftover SQLite stuff from the original project and have to write your routes in `routes.swift`